# wordpress wp-admin/php.ini causes blank page when not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

We have a site that is up and running and working fine.

We recently got a task to increase the file upload limit, to do this we added a php.ini file with the following lines.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

When placed in the root we could see it taking effect (by checking phpinfo file in root) but it wouldn't work for admin until we copied the php.ini file into the wp-admin folder.

After this we could successfully upload larger files and the front and back end showed no issues.

An issue we didn't notice until a couple days later is that the /wp-admin/ url shows a blank page if you are not logged in.

You can still log in via the wp-login.php url and everything will work correctly once you are logged in.

I've checked the error logs and found nothing . it will only start working when we remove/rename the php.ini file. I've also tried turning on debuging in the php.ini or removing everything to have an empty php.ini file but all these changes still cause a blank /wp-admin/ url.

I also tried editing the /wp-admin/index.php file adding the following lines. Adding echo and die statements worked but trying to cause error report printing did not.

```
// this works
echo "test a";
die;

// this does not
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Site info

Wordpress version 4.8.1

PHP Version 7.0.25

Comment: Not related to your blank screen problem, but in many hosting environments it is possible to make php.ini recursive, so it gets applied to sub-directories too. Google for "recursive php.ini".

Answer (score 0):

wordpress wp-includes folder `default-constants.php'`file edit WP_MEMORY_LIMIT

watch the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojCnNgvWt9E