# Wordpress Blank page both in front and admin panel

Tags: html, wordpress, connection, whitespace

i have uploaded wordpress website on server, but after uploading website only showing blank page in front end and in admin panel.
i don't know how to fix it. 
connection has established successfully. 
Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: please change url also in website database.

Comment: already done sir.

Comment: check for `localhost` in your SQL file and replace them with you web URL. You may be replaced `http://localhost/XXX` with your web url but some of the URLs may contain escape string url.

Comment: check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424381/wordpress-wp-admin-php-ini-causes-blank-page-when-not-logged-in/47431307#47431307

Comment: can you tell me where to find that SQL file ?

Comment: you can go to MySQL phpmyadmin and browse wp_options table in that you have to update "home_url" and "site_url" from localhost URL to your current domain URL.

Comment: Open your SQL file. I suggest you must use a text editor like Sublime. Press CTRL + H. Find "localhost" and replace with "yoursite.com".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );

Paste it into your wp-config file, hope this works for you

Otherwise, try to delete your plugin one by one and load the browser may be this is due to plugin confliction.

or try to change the PHP version from cpanel.